# Spring and hibernate using multiple datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to use two database on my project, so I use two Hibernate properties to create two `SessionFactory` and `TransactionManager`.

The problem is that I use Java configuration on my project, which is

```
package config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:hibernate_master.properties" })
public class HibernateMasterConfig {
@Resource
private Environment masterEnvironment;

/**
 * 
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "masterSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    System.out.println(masterEnvironment.hashCode());
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(masterEnvironment
.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
dataSource.setUrl(masterEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));

dataSource.setUsername(masterEnvironment
.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
dataSource.setPassword(masterEnvironment
.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

    return dataSource;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param s
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
@Resource
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory masterSessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(masterSessionFactory);
    return txManager;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @return
 */
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", masterEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", masterEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", masterEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", masterEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}
}
```

The slave configuration is similar to the master configuration, just changed all `master` to `slave`.

```
package config;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:hibernate_slave.properties" })
public class HibernateSlaveConfig {
@Resource
private Environment slaveEnvironment;

/**
 * SessionFactory
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "slaveSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "slaveDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    System.out.println(slaveEnvironment.hashCode());
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(slaveEnvironment
    .getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(slaveEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(slaveEnvironment
    .getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(slaveEnvironment
    .getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param s
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "slaveTransactionManager")
@Resource
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory slaveSessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(slaveSessionFactory);
    return txManager;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", slaveEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", slaveEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", slaveEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", slaveEnvironment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}
```

}

I use two sessionFactory like this

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
/**
 * master SessionFactory
 */
@Resource(name = "masterSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory masterSessionFactory;

/**
 * slave SessionFactory
 */
 @Resource(name = "slaveSessionFactory")
 private SessionFactory slaveSessionFactory;

@Override
public boolean addUser(String email, String password) {
    Session session = masterSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    session.save(user);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isUserExist(String email) {
    Session session = masterSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    System.out.println(masterSessionFactory.getProperties());
    final String HQL = "select email from User u where u.email='" + email + "'";
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Query<String> query = session.createQuery(HQL);
    if (0 == query.list().size())
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

After testing, 
I found that the operation on master database didn't work, it affected the 
slave database instead. I printed the content of the environment, which shows the same result in master and slave configuration. I guess that these two configuration refer the same environment object and the slave configuration is the later one to update this environment object so the operations all works on slave database.

So how can I configure two independent environment to create two `sessionFactory`?

The master configuration properties is

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3307/tickets?
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = xxxxx
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

And the master database is on port 3307, slave database on 3308. I'm sure the content of configuration and the map is proper because when I delete the slave configuration, all operation can work on the master database properly.

Comment: what datasource are you using in your dao ?

Comment: @JEY mysql, I will update the details in properties.

Comment: `After test, I found that ... on master database didn't work, it affected the slave database` are you sure you change configuration?

Comment: And also, did you trying to implement balance loading inside of java code?

Comment: Please post your entire configuration, including your slave sessionFactory.

Is the slave one setting the datasource to be the same as the master ?

Comment: @degr no balance loading, just some simple SQL operation. I've updated the question

Comment: Did you miss @transactional? Specify your transactional manager in it while modifying multiple databases.

Comment: Ok, I can't find a bug inside of your code. Can you remove all code, related to slave database and repeat your actions. Is result same? What will happen if you will remove all information about master database and repeat your actions?